# How to get the part of xml file in JAVA using JAXB as a string

Tags: java, eclipse, jaxb

I have the following XML file.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<school>
<student>
    <firstname name="ankush">
    </firstname>
    <lastname>thakur</lastname>
    <email>beingjavaguy.gmail.com</email>
    <phone>7678767656</phone>
    <address>
      <houseNo> </houseNo>
      <street> </street>
      <city> </city>
      <pincode> </pincode>
    </address>
</student>
```

from the above xml file I want to get the node as string like below

```
 <address>
   <houseNo> </houseNo>
   <street> </street>
   <city> </city>
   <pincode> </pincode>
 </address>
```

i.e. I want to parse the whole XML file to the java model, but content between `<address>` and `</address>` to be parsed as a string in the model. How this is possible with JAXB?

EDIT:
Content between `<address>` and `</address>` is dynamic, i.e. can may contains different elements.

Answer (score 1):

You can use cdata

```
 <sometext>
<![CDATA[ They're saying "x < y" & that "z > y" so I guess that means that z > x ]]>
</sometext>
```

You can see more here https://www.w3resource.com/xml/attribute.php

Comment: Unfortunately, in my case, I can not use cdata. I'm looking for another solution

Comment: then can you create address  class and override toString method to generate that xml as string and use that